# Limits of sequences of sets. Are the limit points always included?

Tags: limits

---

[*Note: edited 2024-01-10 after close. Author's own answer has been appended!*]

[*2024-01-13: minor  cleanup (after reopen).*]

---

This is a request for clarification regarding taking the limit of a sequence of sets. (I failed to find a similar enough question in a quick scan here.)

Let me build the question by simple examples.

For a start consider the sequence $(x_n; n=0,1,2,\dots)$. It is convergent and has the limit $x$. We say $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$$

Next level: consider 10 parallel sequences $$(x_{k,n}; k=1\dots 10; n=0,1,2,\dots).$$ For each fixed $k$, $(x_{k,n})$ is convergent and has the limit $x_k$. Collect these sequences as a sequence of sets, like this: $$ X_n=\{x_{k,n}; k=1\dots 10\} $$
(For simplicity, avoiding to deal with duplicate set members, assume all $x_{n,k}$ and all $x_k$ are distinct.)

Now I hope you will agree with me that $$X_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=X,\text{where}$$ $$ X=\{x_k; k=1\dots 10\}. $$

Next level: For all $n$, accumulate all sequence members that we have seen so far, into one set.

$$ A_n=\bigcup_{m=0}^n X_m $$ $$ =A_{n-1}\cup X_n \ (\text{when }n>0 ) $$

Now the **question** is: what is
$$ A_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n
\ ?$$

I do assume those expressions are equal, yes? If not, please refer to them separately as $A_{u\infty}$ vs $A_{lim\infty}$ in your replies.

More specifically, is it
$$ A_\infty= A_{\infty(shallow)}=\{x: x\in X_n \text{ for some } n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
or is it
$$ A_\infty= A_{\infty(deep)}=
A_{\infty(shallow)}
 \cup X_\infty$$
Where the latter version truly has progressed into infinity and thereby includes the limit points of the sequences.

[*Edit 2024-01-10: the following remarks have been largely obsoleted by later insights*]

> As answers/discussion to other questions here I have seen arguments that $A_\infty$ only contains the iteration members $x_{k,n}$ for all $n$, and *not* the limit points $x_k$. (My interpretation of the motivation is to this effect: $A_\infty$ is to be regarded as the result of an infinite iterative enumeration process, as opposed to $X_\infty$ that is to be seen as a limit process applied to a sequence.)
>
> But according to my own logic, I feel the mathematical apparatus is inconsistent if not $A_\infty$ (or at least $A_{lim\infty}$) always  includes it all, including all limits. (I would be more inclined to accept that the $A_{u\infty}$ notation is different and used for the case when the limits points should not be included in the complete set.)

To spice up the example, we could assume that all $x_{k,n}$ are rational numbers while all limits $x_k$ are irrational.

The answer to this riddle is important for my understanding of some other constructions of transfinite sets. However I tried to keep this example as simplistic and boiled down as possible for the purpose of this question.

---

Update, in reply to a comment requesting me to define what kind of limit I had in mind. I wasn't aware that there were competing definitions. (Isn't math just  more elusive the deeper I try to get into it :)

Checking the neighborhood of the given Wikipedia links, I found that I naturally opt for this one:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#

That is: page
"Limit inferior and limit superior"; section "Sequences of sets"; subsection "General set convergence", i.e. *not* assuming discrete metric, for example.

---

[*Update 2024-01-10 after close*]

*I discovered an answer and I  was about to post it as an Answer to myself. However the q got closed, so I'm adding it here instead.*

## Answer

The answer is *heavily* based on the *general* def. of "the limit of a sequence of sets" found in the Wikipedia link given above. The metric space is here taken to be the real numbers, with the standard Euclidean metric.

First,

> Now I hope you will agree with me that
> $$X_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=X,\text{where}$$ $$ X=\{x_k; k=1\dots
>  10\}. $$

It seems the notation for a limit of seq. of sets should be without the "${n\to\infty}  $". But indeed we have, under the stated assumptions, and since the contained number seqs $(x_{k,n})$ are convergent:
$$X_\infty=\lim X_n=X. $$

Second,

There has been a confusion: the following identity is **not** necessarily true, because the limit operation on a seq of sets is not simply modifying the union operation as it may seem here:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}(\bigcup_{m=0}^n X_m)=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n
$$
Furthermore the LHS should rather read
$$ \lim A_n \text{ where } A_n=\bigcup_{m=0}^n X_m
$$

Third, 
So  in reply to the final question:

> What is  $$ A_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n \ ?$$
> I do assume those expressions are equal, yes? If not, please refer
> to them separately as $A_{u\infty}$ vs $A_{lim\infty}$ in your
> replies.
>
> More specifically, is it  $$A_{\infty(shallow)}=\{x: x\in X_n \text{
>  for some } n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$  or is it  $$A_{\infty(deep)}=
>  A_{\infty(shallow)}  \cup X_\infty$$

I will refer to the two separately and say

$$
A_{u\infty}=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n=
A_{\infty(shallow)}
$$
$$
A_{lim\infty}=\lim A_n=A_{\infty(deep)}
$$

The latter is again by the stated def of limit. We have, thanks to the convergent sequences contained in $A_n$,

$$
\lim\sup A_n=
\lim\inf A_n=
\lim A_n
$$

Working it out by the definitions, it is easiest to begin with $\lim\inf A_n$.

$x\in\lim\inf A_n $ if the seq of sets $(A_n)$ contains a number sequence that converges to $x$.

$x\in\lim\sup A_n $ if the seq of sets $(A_n)$ contains a *subsequence* that likewise converges to $x$. Observe that $(A_n)$ is a subseq of itself.

The "shallow" members of $A_{lim\infty}$ are all the sequence members $x_{k,n}$. They each form a constant seq in $(A_n)$ from some $n$ and on, thereby they all qualify as members of $\lim A_n$.

---

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You need to define a limit first. There are various definitions of set limits such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, I have now updated the question in response to this. I want to keep it simple and at the same time stay as close to general basics as possible.

Comment: From OP: It bugs me why this q remains closed without any feedback. I addressed the one comment saying its not clear what im asking for. *After* this the q was closed. After that I edited, adding my own answer that imo should clarify anything that remained unclear about the question. To that I have only seen a standard response that the edit failed to resolve the problem. Please specify the remaining problem.

Comment: It is frustrating. Unrelated, it might help to make the question a little more concise. As it is it requires a lot of reading to figure out what you are asking. Of course, that would not guarantee a reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author's own answer to the qeustion is given  as addendum to the Q text, as you can see. (The question was closed at the time and the normal Answer format was turned off.)

I still would encourage anyone who is willing to share more knowledge about it to write an alternative answer.