# Constructing the reals using limit of a sequence of sets containing rationals

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers, rational-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

This is a follow-up to the question:
[1] [Paradox: Creating an uncountable set of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841890/paradox-creating-an-uncountable-set-of-natural-numbers).

There is also a relation to this q:
[2]
[Limits of sequences of sets. Are the limit points always included?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841074/limits-of-sequences-of-sets-are-the-limit-points-always-included)

In this version I'm attempting to use a similar technique to create a set of real numbers incrementally, as a sequence of sets. The question is (a) is the technique valid, and (b) how to  correctly compute the cardinality of the resulting set.

Goal: create the set of real numbers in the open interval $(0,1)$ by iteration: successively adding more digits after the "decimal" point and updating the set. Binary representation of the numbers will be used.

Step 0. 
Start with empty set(s): $A_0=X_0=\{\}$.

Step 1. 
Enumerate the first number 0.1; this is all numbers (in the interval) with 1 bit (which literally means binary digit) after the point. Collect these numbers in a set $A_1=\{0.1\}$, and likewise $X_1=\{0.1\}$.

Step 2. 
Enumerate all numbers with 2 bits after the point. Collect the *new numbers from this step* in set $X_2=\{0.01, 0.11\}$. Collect *all the numbers so far*  in $A_2=\{0.1, 0.01, 0.11\}$.

Step $k$. 
In step $k$, for $k>0$, continue the previous enumeration, adding all the numbers with $k$ bits after the point and a "1" in the final position worth $2^{-k}$. Collect all the new numbers in the set $X_k$ and all the numbers in total so far in $A_k$.

Note that the cardinality (number of members) of $A_k$ is $2^k-1$ while that of $X_k$ is $2^{k-1}$.

Note that

(a) The sets $A_k$ can be viewed as a sequence of sets $(A_k)$ with increasing index $k=0,1,2,\dots$. Likewise for $(X_k)$.

(b) Embedded in  $(X_k)$ are many  sequences of (rational) numbers $(x_k)$ with increasing index $k=1,2,\dots$. One example is the seq. $0.01, 0.011, 0.0111, \dots$ which converges to $0.011111\dots=0.1$ (not a very interesting example).

(c) The successive cardinalities of $(A_k)$ can be viewed as a sequence of natural numbers $(s_k)$ with increasing index $k=0,1,2,\dots$; where $s_k=2^k-1$.

(d) It takes an infinite number of steps to reach infinite number of digits after the point, required for constructing irrational (and cyclic rational) numbers. So $k$ must approach infinity. Not only approach - it needs to *reach* infinity (such as $\omega$ or $\aleph_0$).

So now one would like to do
$$ \lim A_k $$
In order to get a set $A_\infty$, or rather $A_\omega$ or $A_{\aleph_0}$,  containing all the numbers.

But now you may argue: I have basically described an enumeration. Enumerations are inherently countable and not powerful enough to construct something uncountable, such as the real interval $(0,1)$.  Having iterated for all [finite] $k$, all I will get is all the rational numbers between 0 and 1 such that their binary repr. is non-cyclic.

Here is my counter-argument.

First, let's *not* use the "set-theoretic limit" based on a discrete metric. Let's use the most general definition of "limit of a sequence of sets", and specify that we are using the standard Euclidean metric for convergence of numeric sequences.

Second, It is slightly easier to reason about $(X_k)$ than $(A_k)$.

Third, I will actually do
$$ \limsup X_k $$
because $\limsup$ is the most liberal in accepting limits of all convergent *subseqences* of $(X_k)$, as members of the resulting set.

Fourth, observe that $ \limsup X_k $, according to its definition, *does* include any limit value that corresponds to any *convergent* subseq of numbers found across all $X_k$. Surely this is going to include an amount of irrational numbers.

Can I prove
$$ \limsup A_k=(0,1), $$
as in containing all the real numbers in $(0,1)$? No. But I think I have a strong argument that $ \limsup$ of $X_k$ and $A_k$ at least contains more than just rational nums.

Regarding $\limsup A_k$, observe that every new member contributed to $A_k$ for some $K$ will remain for all $k>K$. Every such member is a *constant* number sequence that will survive in $\limsup A_k$ (as well as in $\liminf$).

That's a very long text again.

Repeating the **questions**.

Do you believe that this construction can yield all the reals in $(0,1)$? If not, why, and is there a correct way to get there using an exponential growth process? If not, is there another way?

How does one evaluate the cardinality of the final step, $\limsup A_k$? I suppose it is not by simply taking $\lim s_k$ as defined above (seq of successive cardinalities of $A_k$).

---

[*Addendum 2024-01-15, sharpening the argument*]

> Can I prove
> $$ \limsup A_k=(0,1), $$
> as in containing all the real numbers in $(0,1)$? No.

Later I came up with a formal argument in favor of this, that to me appears to work as a proof.

Consider any real number $x$ in $(0,1)$. In order to make it more interesting, consider in particular when $x$ is irrational, though this is not required for the argument.

For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K$ such that for every $k>K$, there exists a number $x_k \in A_k$ such that $|x_k-x| < \epsilon$. This paraphrases the definition of a convergent number sequence. This also paraphrases the existence of a convergent number sequence within the sequence of sets $(A_k)$, as stated in the general definition of "$\liminf A_k$". Due to obeying said definitions, $x \in \liminf A_k$.

To see more clearly that such a $K$ always exists, let $\epsilon_K=2^{-K}$, and observe that this is the finest resolution in $A_K$, and therefore for any $x$ we will find an $x_K \in A_K$ such that $|x_K-x| \le \epsilon_K$. For $A_{K+1}$ and beyond, we can ensure that strictly less than will hold.

When the above is understood, it is easily understood that $x$ will likewise qualify as a member of $\limsup A_k$, so we do have
$$
\limsup A_k = \liminf A_k = \lim A_k = [0,1] \text{ in } \mathbb{R}.
$$
Note that by necessity the interval became closed: due to the workings of $\lim A_k$, limit points $0$ and $1$ must also become members.

I will furthermore claim that the same is true for $\lim X_k$. (The argumentation needs slight modification but to the same result.)

Example:
Binary number $0.101001000100001\dots$ corresponds to convergent sequence $\{$ $x_1=0.1$ in $A_1$, $x_2=x_1=0.10$ in $A_2$ as well as $A_1$, $x_3=0.101$ in $A_3$, $x_4=x_3=0.1010$ in $A_4$ and $A_3$, $\dots\}$. I am "hand-picking" the numbers to fit the sequence I want, but this is within my interpretation of the rules of the game.

For $\lim X_k$, the same example can be turned into this sequence instead, where each steps always adds one significant digit to the string of digits:
$\{0.1, 0.11, 0.101, 0.1011, 0.10101, 0.101001, 0.1010011, \dots\}$.

Why am I writing all this? Well, initially I wanted advice in understanding how this works, but then I came up with this addendum, turning into an argument against people saying that it is not possible to construct the reals using an iterative process like the one I described. Of course, I would like to be told if I made amateur mistakes in the reasoning. I challenge you, the reader, to prove me wrong!

Comment: "But now you may argue: I have basically described an enumeration. "  You may argue that but you'd be wrong.  It's not an enumeration as it *only* enumerates those with finite number of digits.  Not a single one with infinite digits is enumerated.

Comment: @fleablood It's not an enumeration of what? "Not a single one with infinite digits is enumerated", this is true, except that the final "limit" stage produces them all with a bang.

Comment: ...Arguably, that "final bang" isn't an enumeration. On the other hand, the whole thing can be seen as an enumeration of sets of numbers, all the way to infinite length of the numbers, rather than an enumeration of numbers.

Comment: "'limit' stage" is just plain nonsense though.  As is "all the way to infinite length of the numbers".

Comment: @fleablood and others: For the sake of improving my understanding of these concepts (constructing infinite sets of different sizes; infinite sequences of numbers and sets, limits of those, and understanding the size of the limit set), please elaborate where the nonsense is. I would like to know if there is anything wrong with the result of $\lim A_k$ as I described it in the question (using the given definitions that I referred to). An answer telling me either that my reasoning is correct, or why it is wrong, would be most helpful.

Comment: "On the other hand, the whole thing can be seen as an enumeration of sets of numbers"  And enumeration of set!!!S!!!! of numbers, is not itself a single SET_ (**singular**) of numbers listed in a single list one after another.

Comment: " I would like to know if there is anything wrong with the result of limAk"  Everything is WRONG with it.  A limit is a numeric value that is expressible as an object itself. You are trying to have a limit be a list, not a number.  Even if the concept of an THING limit were possible, you must actually have a THING produced. Not a concept of THINGIES getting longer but not ever actually produce.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to "have a limit be a list". I'm strictly following the definition of "limit of a sequence of sets" acc to Wikipedia article "Limit supremum and limit infimum". The "thing" is a set in this case and the limit is itself a set. The Cantor set is constructed in a similar way as the limit of a set sequence, although I think a different metric is used in that case.